# How can I conditionally add Javascript component current date?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

TextInput is a component. I want to set a current Date for the part with `formKey = {'signDate'}` using the TextInput component. 
I have shared the use of component below. 
If conditionally `formKey = {'signDate'}`, 
I want to send a current Date to the changeSelected method.
If the key is not 'signDate', it should set the input value.
How can I do that?

**TextInput usage**

```
<TextInput
  fieldName={'Date'}
  addClassName={'orange-text'}
  formKey={'signDate'}
  disabled={true}
/>
```

**TextInput.js**

```
<Form.Group controlId={formKey}>
  {fieldName && (<Form.Label>{fieldName}</Form.Label>)}
    <Form.Control type={type}
          placeholder={placeholder}
          required={required}
          name={formKey}

          onBlur={e => {
             let val = e.target.value
                 if (changeSelected) {
                     changeSelected(val)
                       }
                   }}

             onChange={evt => updateValue(evt)}
             value={input.value}
             disabled={disabled}
             maxLength={maxLength}
             className={(addClassName ? ' ' + addClassName : '')}
       />

 <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid" style={{
      width: '8rem',
      color : 'red'
  }}>
       {validationError}
  </Form.Control.Feedback>
</Form.Group>
```

Comment: you already have `formKey` available and being used, within the scope available to changeSelected.  Can't you just reference it directly in your call to changeSelected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CodeSandbox Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-water-3oj8i?file=/src/TextInput.js

`formKey` is already available and used in the scope available to your call to `changeSelected`.  You should be able to use it directly:

`changeSelected(formKey === 'signDate' ? new Date().toLocaleDateString() : e.target.value)`

Note: You didn't specify what kind of Date string you want to be there (which by the way is locale dependent and should be parsed before being sent back to server).  Your input is just a normal input with no schema applied it, so I just guessed that you want a bare date string.  Is there a reason you aren't using a Date control (available to react-bootstrap which you are using)?

Are you perhaps actually just having trouble with formatting a Date string?
[toLocaleDateString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString)
[toLocaleString](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString)
[Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat)

Answer (score 2):

```
if (this.props.formKey === 'signDate') {
   const date = new Date()
   changeSelected(date)
} else {
   changeSelected(e.target.value)
}
```

you need to look for a prop called `formKey` and ensure it has the value `signDate` then call the function with a `new Date()` passed in. `else` call it with the input val

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are using ReactJS, there are multiple ways to add /include elements conditionally, good post on the same 
https://scotch.io/tutorials/7-ways-to-implement-conditional-rendering-in-react-applications

Comment: This should be added as a comment rather then a answer.

Comment: Or turned into an actual answer by showing an implementation, rather than a link to a possible method that isn't proven to be a practical improvement to OP's approach, which is just to use a variable to control calls to his handler (possibly no more than a one line change)